# Using $uibModal from a factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, angular-services

I've been playing around with using uibModal from a factory instead of using it from within my controller. The dialog comes up, and the field data is returned to the service when OK is clicked, but, I don't know how to get the data back to my controller, where it will be added to my model Any pointers?

Here is my factory code:

```
    'use strict';

angular.module('ngTableScopeApp')
.factory('DialogService', function($uibModal){

  var DialogService = {};
  DialogService.newObj = {};

  DialogService.addNewItem = function(template, $q){

    this.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: template,
      controller: function($scope, $uibModalInstance){
        $scope.ok = function () {
          $uibModalInstance.close($scope);
          return this.newObj;
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
          $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
          return null;
        };
      }
    });
  };
  return DialogService;
});
```

Here is the controller code:

```
    'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name ngTableScopeApp.controller:MainCtrl
 * @description
 * # MainCtrl
 * Controller of the ngTableScopeApp
 */
angular.module('ngTableScopeApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function (NgTableParams, DummyData, DialogService) {

    var self = this;
    self.data = DummyData.generateData(1);

    var createUsingFullOptions = function() {

      var initialParams = {
        count: 10 // initial page size
      };
      var initialSettings = {
        // page size buttons (right set of buttons in demo)
        counts: [5, 10, 25, 50],
        // determines the pager buttons (left set of buttons in demo)
        paginationMaxBlocks: 13,
        paginationMinBlocks: 2,
        dataset: self.data //DummyData.generateData(1)
      };
      return new NgTableParams(initialParams, initialSettings);
    };

    self.customConfigParams = createUsingFullOptions();

    self.addNewItem = function(){

        DialogService.addNewItem('views/addNewItem.html', self);
    };
  });
```

Comment: Hope you can access the data from controller using DialogService.newObj     variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `close` method available on `$uibModalInstance` service, in which you can pass data while closing a popup. And then you can utilize `result` promise object which does gets called when modal gets closed. Whatever data passed from `$uibModalInstance.close` method is available there. Make sure you are returning promise returned by `$uibModal.open` method.

**Factory**

```
DialogService.addNewItem = function(template, $q){

    this.modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          templateUrl: template,
          controller: function($scope, $uibModalInstance){
            $scope.ok = function () {
               $uibModalInstance.close({ data: 'OK Called' });
            };

            $scope.cancel = function () {
               $uibModalInstance.close({ data: 'Cancel Called' });
            };
          }
        });
    };
    return this.modalInstance;
};
```

**Controller**

```
DialogService.addNewItem('views/addNewItem.html', self)
.result.then(function(data) {
   console.log("data", data); // print { data: 'MyCustomData' }
});
```

**Modal Controller**

```
$scope.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close({data: 'MyCustomData'});
};
```

Comment: should return the `$uibModal.open()` instance  from service method

Comment: also for more generic use can return `modalInstance.result`. Then controller just manages the promise

Comment: @charlietfl but then what if user wants to put handler over `.opened` & other options, they will be hidden

Comment: Could pass callbacks as arguments. I have some modal factories that have sub methods also that then call function that wraps `$uibModal.open` and configure it differently depending on case

Comment: @charlietfl I agree with what you're saying, but I'd rather prefer to whole object.

Comment: right...depends on use case... I rarely access much other than the `result` and customize the `open` object in my factory

Comment: @charlietfl You're correct!, but if you have any plugin to modify your UI after popups render, I generally I'd used `rendered` option, sometimes other options as well. Its really depends on use case

Comment: i often do things like `openModal( type, data, opts)` then use that in factory to customize which modal controller and other config etc

Comment: @charlietfl Oh! I like that way, I'll follow that going forward, thanks  :)

Comment: Great, thanks everyone. I knew there was a promise, I just couldn't figure out how to handle it from within the controller.

Comment: @user675712 Glad to know that, it helped you, Thanks & Cheers :)